# Flip views in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a `UIView` which has a button, On the button's tap I am showing a new `UIView` which contain a `UINavigationBar` and a `UITableView`. Is there any way to animate a flip effect on button's tap and load the view and also vice versa ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is some code that may help

```
- (void)flipAction:(id)sender
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    // checks to see if the view is attached
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:([logTextView superview] ?
                                    UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                           forView:[self view] cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:([logTextView superview] ?
                                    UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                           forView:[[self navigationController] view] cache:YES];
    if ([logTextView superview])
    {
        [logTextView removeFromSuperview];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FTP Log", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(viewFtpLog)];
    }
    else
    {
        [[self view] addSubview:logTextView];
        [[[self navigationItem] rightBarButtonItem] release];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(flipAction:)];
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

For you, you might want to get the UIView for your table view.  The button is what triggers the flip

Comment: Also, I am keeping a reference to logTextView as an @property in my UIViewController